# Are there apps that let you code ON the iPhone (not FOR the iphone)?

Tags: iphone

I'm just wondering if anybody knows of any simple IDEs or interpreters or anything that lets you play around with code on your iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

**Mides IDE**: lets you make php based web aplications **ON THE IPHONE** http://www.owensperformance.com/mides/

**Interface**: Lets you make IPHONE APPS (without coding) **ON THE IPHONE**

**ICode**: The same as "Interface" but with coding.

If you are interested in one of them just type the name of the app in itunes. :)

DD